# Meteor settings.json (public) is removing spaces

Tags: meteor, google-analytics

I'm using [okgrow:analytics](https://github.com/okgrow/analytics) and I've noticed that when the app is bundled Google Analytics isn't working. 
After doing some research I've discovered that the **meteor_runtime_config** variable (that holds the Public settings), has spaces removed, which makes it GoogleAnalytics.

This means the plugin doesn't work anymore (because it's searching for "Google Analytics").

How can I quickly fix this without forking their plugin (tried adding %20, it just escaped that to %2520) ?